# Silk Test- Unable to record a table

Tags: silktest

I'm trying to capture a table from an application build in PowerBuilder,It records table as Control always instead of table which doesn't allows any table functions on it. Can anybody guide me with this?

e.g. Control abcd
        locator "[@priorlabel='abcd'][1]"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Silk Test does not provide specific support PowerBuilder. You might be able to automate the table using a combination of `Click()`, `TypeKeys()`, `TextClick()` and `ImageClick()`.